# Android SDK Manager Not Loading API level 7

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I m new in Android. I have installed installer_r18-windows , while launching sdk manager form Eclipse==> windows , it started downloading all the api level but i cant see api level 7. there are 8,10,13,15 api levels.

I had created environemnt with same installer two weeks ago but in different machine.I dont know what is going wrong this time.

I have already spent hours on google but cant find anything.please help

Comment: Same here. I think one of Google's revisions might have cleaned up everything >7 API.

Comment: same for me too...
waiting for its answer.